# Querying composite keys in couchdb python

Tags: python, couchdb

I have a composite key `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` and am trying to query it using python couchdb view.  I typically am after one of the keys at a time, excluding the others.

For instance, to query for `key='a'`, the only thing I've found that works is:

```
results=db.view(docname, startkey=['a'], endkey=['azz']).
```

I thought the `{}` worked with either `key`, `startkey` or `endkey`, but they seem to have no effect.

Actually, I'm usually after:  "Find all documents that have `"a"` and `"b"`, or have `"a"`, `"c"` and `"e"`, etc.  I've tried making separate views for `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, etc. and doing separate queries, but some of the queries are based on keys that are not a-->e, like `"x"`, `"y"` or `"z"`.  So, for those, I try to make a view with keys that look like: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "z"]`.  It's very expensive, time wise to bring over the whole document (with `'include_docs'`), and I only ever need to output `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` & `e`.

I'm trying to find the best combination of composite keys and minimal document transfer per query.  I think it will work if I can figure out to fetch `"a"` only, then `"b"` only, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly: You are trying to get documents that contain two or more values. This could be tags, for example.

You have two possibilities:

1. Use a full-text search engine like couchdb-lucene or elasticsearch
2. Emit a key for every combination of keys. For a document with tags ["a", "b", "x"] you would emit:

View results:

```
[{key: ["a"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["a", "b"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["a", "x"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["a", "b", "x"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["b"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["b", "x"], id: 1, value: null}
{key: ["x"], id: 1, value: null}]
```

With include_docs you get the corresponding document at query time. Keep in mind though that this approach uses a lot of disk space. You could create a single design doc just with this view to see how much disk space the view results need.

Hope this helps! If you provided a real example I could probably give a better answer ;-)

Yours, Bernhard